# Javascript regex: test if text contains only characters from a set

Tags: javascript, regex

How it is better to check  (test) if text contains only characters from set (for example if text contains only punctuation marks)

```
var regex = /[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g

res = text.replace(regex, '')

if (res) return false
```

so I made it with replace is it possible to do it with regex.test?

Comment: Are you sure that `,-\` and `\-_` do what you think they do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is. There are two possibilities. One is, that you use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to assert that the full string is made up of these:

```
var regex = /^[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]+$/;
if(regex.test(text))
```

Alternatively you can use a negated character class and see whether it matches and then again negate the result

```
var regex = /[^\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/;
if(!regex.test(text))
```

Note that `,-\/` is a range that includes `,-./`. This is redundant and may become a source of errors if the character class is ever changed. You might want to simplify your character class to:

```
[.,\/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()-]
```

(Or the negated version of that, depending on which approach you choose.)